# Jupyter python2 notebook doesn't find a module when invoked in a subprocess with runipy

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a number of notebooks that I test with [runipy](https://github.com/paulgb/runipy) from a Docker container.
There's a main python test script that is invoked via the Docker entry point.
This script creates a subprocess in the container in which it runs runipy.

```
bash_command = "runipy --quiet " + notebook_path + " " + output_file_path
process = subprocess.Popen(bash_command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I have some custom code that parses the output .ipynb file looking for issues.

This worked like a charm until I introduced a new library (boto3).
It was properly installed and "import boto3" works both when called from python directly or when using the Jupyter Notebook web UI, 
but when running the same notebook with runipy in the spawned process I get:

```
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

Syspath print out when running the code from the Jupyter Web UI:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Syspath print out from the automated runipy invocation:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions', '/root/.ipython']
```

(They're the same, except for : '/root/.ipython' that appears only in the latter)

Any ideas?